# plotting with drawnow in python

Tags: python, drawnow

I am trying to monitor sensor data in real-time, but the plot shows nothing, below is just an example.
can anyone explain to me how come the result is showing nothing?

[image]

```
import datetime
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from drawnow import *
from matplotlib.dates import AutoDateLocator, AutoDateFormatter, date2num

i = 0
x = 0
y = 0
FirstTime = str('00:00')
LastTime = str('00:00')

def CreatePlot():
    figure = plt.subplot()
    plt.plot([],[])
    date_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(LastTime, '%H:%M')
    int_date = date2num( date_datetime)
    locator = AutoDateLocator()
    figure.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
    figure.xaxis.set_major_formatter( AutoDateFormatter(locator) )
    min_date = date2num( datetime.datetime.strptime(FirstTime, '%H:%M') )
    max_date = date2num( datetime.datetime.strptime(LastTime, '%H:%M') )
    plt.xlim(min_date, max_date)
    plt.plot(x,y, 'r-')
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

while True:
    x = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=i)
    x = datetime.datetime.strftime(x,'%H:%M')
    if i == 0:
        FirstTime = x
    else:
        LastTime = x
    y = (2*i)+2
    if i>500:
        break
    else:
        drawnow(CreatePlot)
        plt.pause(0.0001)
        i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, so I am gonna explain it to help someone else like me,
the first issue is changing date format to string with strftime,
plotting string in x-axis is not auto-formattable,
also following commands are redundant:

```
min_date = date2num( datetime.datetime.strptime(FirstTime, '%H:%M') )
max_date = date2num( datetime.datetime.strptime(LastTime, '%H:%M') )
plt.xlim(min_date, max_date)
```

in addition, to make a better view someone can add the following commands too:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator
from matplotlib.dates import AutoDateLocator, AutoDateFormatter
.
.
.
.
ax0 = plt.subplot(2,2,1)
locator = AutoDateLocator()
ax0.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
formatter = AutoDateFormatter(locator)
ax0.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax0.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator())
```